# Deconvolution to obtain the unit response

Tags: signal-processing, convolution, deconvolution

I have measured two signals as time series. One of them is the input of the system and the other one is the output.

I assume that if I know the unit response of the system, then I may obtain the output by the convolution of this unit response and the input time series.

On the other side, is it possible to obtain the unit response if I know the input and the output on a long term? Is it possible to obtain this unit response by deconvolution?

Or how is it possible to obtain the unit response function/vector if I measure some natural process variables?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to estimate the [transfer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function). There are different methods to do it. Many of these methods are based on the frequency domain. In case you provide additional information, you can peak up the best method for you.